# Formatting phone number to E164 format in Android

Tags: android, number-formatting, phonenumberutils

I want convert every phone number from conatct in device to E164 format.
So, I used opensource below.

[libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n)

So I used it like here.

```
Phonenumber.PhoneNumber formattedNumber = null;
String formatted = null;

try {
    formattedNumber = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumber, "KR");
    formatted = phoneUtil.format(formattedNumber,PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164);

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(formatted) == false && formatted.length() > 0 && StringUtils.isEmpty(name) == false && name.length() > 0) {
        listName.add(name);
        listPhoneNumber.add(formatted);
    }
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
    continue;
}
```

And I read that this library is used by the Android framework since 4.0.

> The Java version is optimized for running on smartphones, and is used by the Android framework since 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich).

I want to use this from Android SDK. So I found this. Android SDK provides this [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html)
.

And there is a function

> formatNumberToE164(String phoneNumber, String defaultCountryIso)

It's really easy to use. but API level of this function is 21.

So My question is..How can I use PhoneNumberUtils to convert phonenumber to E164 under API Level 14(ICS) ~ 21?

Thanks.!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is `PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumberToE164(...)` is not available on older devices and there's nothing else in PhoneNumberUtils that does the same job.

I'd suggest using PhoneNumberUtils when available and libphonenumber on older devices, for example:

```
public String formatE164Number(String countryCode, String phNum) {

    String e164Number;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(countryCode)) {
        e164Number = phNum;
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            e164Number = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumberToE164(phNum, countryCode);
        } else {
            try {
                PhoneNumberUtil instance = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
                Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = instance.parse(phNum, countryCode);
                e164Number = instance.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164);

            } catch (NumberParseException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Caught: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                e164Number = phNum;
            }
        }
    }

    return e164Number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tried above code its not working for me also, need to made small changes, am sharing updated code :

```
public String formatE164Number(String countryCode, String phNum) {

    String e164Number;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(countryCode)) {
        e164Number = phNum;
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            /*e164Number = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumberToE164(phNum, countryCode);*/
            e164Number =PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phNum, countryCode);
            Timber.d("e164Number E164 :"+ e164Number);
            Toast.makeText(this,"e164 : "+e164Number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            try {
                PhoneNumberUtil instance = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
                Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = instance.parse(phNum, countryCode);
                e164Number = instance.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
                Timber.d("e164Number E164 : $e164Number");
                Timber.d("e164Number INTERNATIONAL  : "+instance.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL));
                Timber.d("e164Number NATIONAL :  "+instance.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL));
                Timber.d("e164Number RFC3966 :  "+instance.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.RFC3966));

            } catch (NumberParseException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Caught: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                e164Number = phNum;
            }
        }
    }

    return e164Number;
}
```

Now you can method like this :

```
 formatE164Number("US","5712712384");
 (571) 271-2384 


formatE164Number("US","+15712712384");
+1 571-271-2384
```