# Picking contacts number from the contact list and putting it in an EditText

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-contacts

I have an EditText and a Button, the button has an OnClickListener that opens the contacts list with `startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.PICK", android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 1)`.

If the user click on the button, it opens the contact so that they can select one, now I want to import that number to the EditText. Is there a way to do that?

Edit: The both the EditText and the button belong to a Fragment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the phone number from selected contact?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696593/how-to-get-the-phone-number-from-selected-contact)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specifically need a phone number to be picked by the user, you can request for a phone-number-picker, instead of a contact-picker like you're doing.

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

The intent data you'll get in return would be for a specific phone row in the Data table:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((requestCode == 1) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER }, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String phone = cursor.getString(0);
                // Do something with phone
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an error on `protedcted` void onActivityResult, saying it clashes with the   one in the android.support.v4.app.Fragment and I should make it public

Comment: great! no problem making it public, it depends on what class you inherit

Comment: Thank you. But just wanted to know if there is a way to filter the number, e.g removing the country code and keeping the number (exemple: +33XX XX XX XXX becomes XX XX XX XXX)

Comment: you need to use Google's `libphonenumber`: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37666789/819355 (just use `PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL` instead of `E164`)